# Webpack issue relating to path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
template: "./src/index.html",
filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.js',
module: {
    rules: [
        {test: /\.js$/,exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {loader: "babel-loader"}
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
            use: [{loader: 'file-loader',options: {}}]
        },
        {test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,use: 'file-loader',},
        {test: /\.csv$/,
            loader: 'csv-loader',
            options: {
                dynamicTyping: true,
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(pdf|gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
            use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(csv|doc|docx)$/,
            loader: 'csv-loader',
            options: {dynamicTyping: true,header: true,skipEmptyLines: true}
        },
        { test: /\.xlsx$/, loader: "webpack-xlsx-loader" },
        {test: /\.(mp3|avi|mov)$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
        { test: /\.(webm|mp4)$/,loader: 'file-loader'},
        { test: /\.(rtf|wexbim)$/,loader: 'raw-loader'}
    ]
},
plugins: [
    htmlWebpackPlugin
],
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host:'192.168.1.166',
    // host:'127.0.0.1',
    port:'8080'
},
devtool: 'inline-source-map'
```

};

I am using `webpack 4` and getting below the following error:

```
"client:168 ./src/components/Fileviewer/drivers/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './audio-viewer' in '/Users/arush.singh/Desktop/arush_desktop_12-Nov-18/react-webpack4/src/components/Fileviewer/drivers'"
```

path issue when i had less files i ignored but now  its becoming very frequent i have tried all resources please check if there is anything wrong i have done:

```
package.json{
 "webpack": "^4.26.0",
 "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
 "webpack-xlsx-loader": "^1.0.0"
}
```

this is the code from the src/components/drivers/index.js  if you want i can provide you more details if you want

```
        src/components/Fileviewer/drivers
export { default as CsvViewer } from './csv-viewer';
export { default as Photo360Viewer } from './photo360-viewer';
export { default as PDFViewer } from './pdf-viewer';
export { default as DocxViewer } from './docx-viewer';
export { default as VideoViewer } from './video-viewer';
export { default as XlsxViewer } from './xlsx-viewer';
export { default as XBimViewer } from './xbim-viewer';
export { default as UnsupportedViewer } from './unsupported-viewer';
export { default as PhotoViewer } from './photo-viewer';
export { default as PhotoViewerWrapper } from './photo-viewer- 
 wrapper';
export { default as AudioViewer } from './audio-viewer';
```

Comment: Need to see the offending `index.js` file please.

Comment: Additionally, where are you calling webpack from, with which commands, what is this config file namesld, and where is it located?

Comment: i have updated the Question please check you will find the code from index.js in it at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a Webpack issue to me?
Could you post your `index.js`'s code from `src/components/Fileviewer/drivers`? I think the problem is likely in there, as that's where the error is springing from.

Comment: i have updated the  Question please check you will find the code from index.js in it at the end

Comment: I have had some typo mistakes ...sorry !

Comment: Okay-- what's the file at "Users/arush.singh/Desktop/arush_desktop_12-Nov-18/react-webpack4/src/components/Fileviewer/drivers/audio-viewer" look like? Looks like it's not properly resolving the file you're trying to import.

Comment: Thank you for you time but now this issue has been resolved